Wrap, fold, or truncate long lines in ltxdoc's macrocode
LaTeX package code sometimes contains very long lines that the developer does not want to break.  For instance, the code may contain an alphabetically sorted list (of long macros, long strings, etc.).  Maintaining the list in sorted order is easy when there is one entry per line, but inconvenient when the entries are broken across multiple lines.
A problem is that, when generating the documented package source with ltxdoc, these long lines end up spilling into the margin or even off the edge of the page.  Here is a minimal example .dtx file:
% \iffalse
%<*internal>
\begingroup
%</internal>
%<*batchfile>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}
%</batchfile>
%<batchfile>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\endgroup
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription
\begin{document}
\title{Example documented source}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package> 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{example}[2024-10-11 v0.1 example]
\def\somemacro{A very long line that we do not want to break in the source code but would like to fold, wrap, or truncate in the documentation.}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode} 
% \Finale

Here is the output:

Is there a relatively simple way of getting the macrocode environment to wrap or fold long lines at the right margin?  (To be clear, wrapping means automatically breaking the lines at whitespace, and folding means automatically breaking lines at a fixed column.)  If there is no such way, is it at least possible to have long lines truncated at the right margin instead of at the right edge of the page?
I understand from the answer to another question that it is possible to redefine the macrocode environment as a suitably styled lstlisting environment from the listings package. However, this has the disadvantage of preventing the indexing of macro names.  Besides lstlistings, there are a lot of other verbatim-like environments that can break long lines, but I think they all suffer from the same disadvantage.
Can we have macrocode (or some other environment) wrap, fold, or truncate long lines and still have the source lines numbered and macro names indexed?

You can add, for example,
% \makeatletter
% \def\@xobeysp{\leavevmode\penalty100\ }
% \makeatother

which will allow lines to be broken at spaces in many cases. It does not always work as well as one might like, but it does help.
[With apologies to wherever/whoever I got this from originally.]
